# htaccess back-reference returning no value for certain matches

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having a really strange issue with a redirect in my .htaccess.

The rule I have set up is:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/$ ?mode=book&permalink=$1
```

It matches both multi-word phrases:
`http://www.fernwoodpublishing.ca/About-Canada-Youth-and-Children/`

and single-word phrases:
`http://www.fernwoodpublishing.ca/Kaandossiwin/`

However, when it does match those single-word phrases, without any hyphens, the backreference isn't passed through properly. So, where the above example SHOULD go to

```
?mode=book&permalink=Kaandossiwin
```

which would work correctly, it instead goes to

```
?mode=book&permalink=
```

which just creates a whole slew of errors and breaks stuff.

I've tried a variant of ways to fix this, and nothing seems to be helping. Anyone more experienced with htaccess have any idea why the back-reference isn't being returned in these specific cases? (I've tested it with other examples and have experienced the same problem precisely, so I'm certain that it's matching in all cases, but only returning the back-reference in those cases where the match contains hyphens.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. I believe the grouping is malformed.

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ ?mode=book&permalink=$1
```

I'd also suggest prefixing your link as this URL format is pretty loose. That is to say it matches any URL with alphanumeric, underscore, or dash at the top level. Something like the following is more flexible.

```
RewriteRule ^book/([\w-]+)/?$ book.php?permalink=$1
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! Unfortunately, my client requested the url structure—otherwise I'd have gone with the /book/ subdirectory structure. It makes things a bit trickier. I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it seems to break the matching altogether. I'm not sure what's going wrong anymore!

Comment: Thanks so much, Jason! Turns out another line in the htaccess was conflicting with this due to a zero-match. I'm really terrible with regular expressions!

Comment: Cool. I was about to second guess myself.